# saltstack - custom module to render a variable inside a pillar

Tags: salt-stack

I am coding a custom module that is executed inside a pillar to set a pillar variable

```
import json

def get_value(key: str) -> str:
    return "foo"
```

I save my file at
`/srv/salt/_modules/my_custom_module.py`
and I use it at my pillar in this way:

```
value: {{ salt['my_custom_module'].get_value('foo') | yaml_encode }}
```

This works perfect! However I want to avoid this module to be sync on minions as this is a "salt-master" only functionality.
I've tried to configure master with

```
runner_dirs:
  - /srv/salt/runners
```

and copy the module to that folder, because runners are modules which are master-side only, however this doesn't work, I've got following error:

```
Jinja variable 'salt.utils.templates.AliasedLoader object' has no attribute 'my_custom_module'
```

Comment: The recommended syntax is `salt["my_custom_module.get_value"]("foo")`

Answer (score 1):

The `salt` loader doesn't contain runners, it contains execution modules.

To call a runner from a pillar template, use [`saltutil.runner`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.saltutil.html#salt.modules.saltutil.runner).

```yaml
value: {{ salt["saltutil.runner"]("myrunner.get_value", arg=["foo"]) | yaml_encode }}
```

Note also that anything under `/srv/salt` will be available to all minions, even if they're not specifically loaded as modules.

If you only use this custom function from pillars, perhaps it should be a [custom pillar](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/development/modules/external_pillars.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need this functions in more places not only pillars, so the question actually is "where should be located custom modules for masters ?"

Comment: There's no particular harm in having it synced everywhere (unless you've put secrets in the code). If you really want to restrict loading, that's what the `__virtual__` function is for.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it creating a folder other than `_modules` and applying following configuration to master at folder `/etc/salt/master.d`:

```
# A list of extra directories to search for Salt modules.

module_dirs:
  - /srv/salt/master/custom/modules/
```

in this way master is able to find it but it is not sync to any minion

see: https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/configuration/master.html#module-dirs